# How to move an iframe on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have a problem with Iframe of Google Maps.
I want to put Google Maps on the left of the form.

The page now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGY05.png
[image]

The code is here :

```
output=embed" height="480" width="640" frameborder="0" 
      marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" 
        "style="position:absolute; left:150; bottom:-10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the iframe in a div and float it to the left and put the form in another div and float that to the left as well.

```
<div style="float:left;">IFRAME CODE</div>
<div style="float:left;">[FORM CODE]</div>
```